# How to show icon depending on which Pressable is pressed in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, icons, state

I have a multiple Pressable component. How can I make it that when I clicked on the Motorcycle pressable, the check icon would be shown beside it and if on the Tricycle Pressable, the check icon would be shown beside it and the one on the Motorcycle icon will be gone.

[image]

I have tried creating a state but it simultaneously set all icons in place. Here is the code:

```
  const [checkIcon, setCheckIcon] = useState(false)

<Pressable
            style={({ pressed }) => [{ opacity: pressed ? 0.4 : 1 }, styles.modalField]}
              onPress={() => setCheckIcon(true)}
            >
              <Image source={require("../assets/motorcycle.png")} style={styles.modalFieldImage} />
              <View style={styles.modalFieldVehicleNameContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.modalFieldText}>Motorcycle</Text>
                <Text style={styles.modalFieldTextDescription}>Cheapest option perfect for small-sized items</Text>
                <Text style={styles.modalFieldTextDescription}>Up to 20 kg</Text>
              </View>
              {
                checkIcon === true ? <Icon name="check" type="font-awesome-5" size={hp("3%")} color="#322C6A" style={styles.modalFieldIcon} /> : null
              }
            </Pressable>

            <Pressable
              style={({ pressed }) => [{ opacity: pressed ? 0.4 : 1 }, styles.modalField]}
              onPress={() => setCheckIcon(true)}
            >
              <Image source={require("../assets/tricycle.png")} style={styles.modalFieldImage} />
              <View style={styles.modalFieldVehicleNameContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.modalFieldText}>Tricycle</Text>
                <Text style={styles.modalFieldTextDescription}>Perfect for multiple medium-sized items</Text>
                <Text style={styles.modalFieldTextDescription}>Up to 70 kg</Text>
              </View>
              {
                checkIcon === true ? <Icon name="check" type="font-awesome-5" size={hp("3%")} color="#322C6A" style={styles.modalFieldIcon} /> : null
              }
            </Pressable>

            <Pressable
              style={({ pressed }) => [{ opacity: pressed ? 0.4 : 1 }, styles.modalField]}
              onPress={() => setCheckIcon(true)}
            >
              <Image source={require("../assets/sedan.png")} style={styles.modalFieldImage} />
              <View style={styles.modalFieldVehicleNameContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.modalFieldText}>Sedan Car</Text>
                <Text style={styles.modalFieldTextDescription}>Good for cakes and multiple small to medium-sized items</Text>
                <Text style={styles.modalFieldTextDescription}>Up to 200 kg</Text>
              </View>
              {
                checkIcon === true ? <Icon name="check" type="font-awesome-5" size={hp("3%")} color="#322C6A" style={styles.modalFieldIcon} /> : null
              }
            </Pressable>
```

Comment: You cannot use 1 state with boolean with this case. You can save index as state for this and render the 'check' mark by `.map()` with index.

Comment: can you give me a brief example on how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an simple example, using a index state to log down which item is selected by user.

Since your list can be generated dynamically, so you may use an array to store all the parameters for rendering and use `map()` to render one by one.

```
const [optionArray, setOptionArray] = useState([
    {
      title: "Motorcycle",
      desc1: "Cheapest option perfect for small-sized items",
      desc2: "Up to 20 kg",
      img: "../assets/motorcycle.png",
    },
    {
      title: "Tricycle",
      desc1: "Perfect for multiple medium-sized items",
      desc2: "Up to 70 kg",
      img: "../assets/tricycle.png"
    },
    {
      title: "Sedan Car",
      desc1: "Good for cakes and multiple small to medium-sized items",
      desc2: "Up to 200 kg",
      img: "../assets/sedan.png",
    }
  ]);
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(-1);   //Nothing is selected with initial render

  const ListItem = ({option, index}) =>{
    return(
      <Pressable
        style={({ pressed }) => [{ opacity: pressed ? 0.4 : 1 }, styles.modalField]}
        onPress={() => setSelectedIndex(index)}
      >
        <Image source={option.img} style={styles.modalFieldImage} />
        <View style={styles.modalFieldVehicleNameContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.modalFieldText}>{option.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.modalFieldTextDescription}>{option.desc1}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.modalFieldTextDescription}>{option.desc2}</Text>
        </View>
        {
          index === selectedIndex && <Icon name="check" type="font-awesome-5" size={hp("3%")} color="#322C6A" style={styles.modalFieldIcon} />
        }
      </Pressable>
    )
  }

  return(
    <View>
      {
        optionArray.map((option, index) => 
          <ListItem option={option} index={index} />
        )
      }
    </View>
  )
```

Also answer by Hardik prajapati is another solution too. That method will not affect the result when the data list is sorted in runtime. But large object modification will trigger re-render for components which may lead to performance issue in some case.

Therefore, you can select different approach for your case.

Comment: thanks, this worked like a charm! its the {
          index === selectedIndex && <Icon name="check" type="font-awesome-5" size={hp("3%")} color="#322C6A" style={styles.modalFieldIcon} />
        } that was confusing for me

Comment: This is a conditional statement. If the condition is true, the JSX component will be rendered. It is equals to your orignial statement `(condition ? <Something /> : null)` but no need to provide `null` for false case.

Answer (score 2):

create Vehicle item array like
`vehicle:[ image:'put your imageUrl', name:'', description:'', clickStatus:true ]`

then use map method  to display  all array item and
when you click on any item update your array with **clickStatus** key
pressable item true and other two item false  and display **Check Icon**  based on true or false

Comment: thank you, i get it, is that the best possible way to do it?

Comment: one question, how do i update the clickStatus? I am new to .map()

Comment: setAbc(prev => {
      let updateItem = prev.map(item => {
        if (item.name === 'put your clickable item name ') {
          item.click = true;
        } else {
          item.click = false;
        }
        return item;
      });
      return updateItem;
    });

Comment: not a best possible way for big array